# Does Javac's StringBuilder optimisation do more harm than good?

Tags: java, string, optimization, javac, stringbuilder

Let's say we have some code such as the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++) {
        s += "really ";
    }
    s += "long string.";
}
```

(Yes, I know a far better implementation would use a `StringBuilder`, but bear with me.)

Trivially, we might expect the bytecode produced to be something akin to the following:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String 
   2: astore_1      
   3: iconst_0      
   4: istore_2      
   5: iload_2       
   6: sipush        10000
   9: if_icmpge     25
  12: aload_1       
  13: ldc           #3                  // String really 
  15: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.concat:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  18: astore_1      
  19: iinc          2, 1
  22: goto          5
  25: aload_1       
  26: ldc           #5                  // String long string.
  28: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/lang/String.concat:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
  31: astore_1      
  32: return
```

However, instead the compiler tries to be a bit smarter - rather than using the concat method, it has a baked in optimisation to use `StringBuilder` objects instead, so we get the following:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: ldc           #2                  // String 
   2: astore_1      
   3: iconst_0      
   4: istore_2      
   5: iload_2       
   6: sipush        10000
   9: if_icmpge     38
  12: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  15: dup           
  16: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  19: aload_1       
  20: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  23: ldc           #6                  // String really 
  25: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  28: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  31: astore_1      
  32: iinc          2, 1
  35: goto          5
  38: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  41: dup           
  42: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  45: aload_1       
  46: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  49: ldc           #8                  // String long string.
  51: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  54: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  57: astore_1      
  58: return
```

However, this seems rather counter-productive to me - instead of using one string builder for the entire loop, one is created for each single concatenation operation, making it equivalent to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++) {
        s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append("really ").toString();
    }
    s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append("long string.").toString();
}
```

**So now instead of the original trivial *bad* approach of just creating lots of string objects and throwing them away, the compiler has produced an *far worse* approach of creating lots of `String` objects, lots of `StringBuilder` objects, calling more methods, and still throwing them all away to generate the same output as without this optimisation.**

So the question has to be - why? I understand that in cases like this:

```
String s = getString1() + getString2() + getString3();
```

...the compiler will create just one `StringBuilder` object for all three strings, so there are cases where the optimisation is useful. However, examing the bytecode reveals that even separating the above case to the following:

```
String s = getString1();
s += getString2();
s += getString3();
```

...means that we're back with the case that three `StringBuilder` objects are individually created. I'd understand if these were odd corner cases, but appending to strings in this way (and in a loop) are really rather common operations.

Surely it would be trivial to determine, at compile time, if a compiler-generated `StringBuilder` only ever appended one value - and if this was the case, use a simple concat operation instead?

This is all with 8u5 (however, it goes back to at least Java 5, probably before.) FWIW, my benchmarks (unsurprisingly) put the manual `concat()` approach 2x3 times faster than using `+=` in a loop with 10,000 elements. Of course, using a manual `StringBuilder` is always the preferable approach, but surely the compiler shouldn't adversely affect the performance of the `+=` approach either?

Comment: Can you link to where it's called an optimisation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1.2

Comment: Did you also try with older versions (Java 6, Java 7) of Java? It might be interesting to find out if you discovered a regression bug here.

Comment: @Gimby I tried with the latest Java 7 also, exactly the same result. (Didn't have Java 6 to hand to try out.)

Comment: I tried it on a Java 6 (first time I used javap, hurray), the output is exactly the same.

Comment: My guess is that they didn't consider it useful enough: if the loop is small, then the performance difference wouldn't matter. If the loop is large, it would make the performance only a bit less awful, and the resulting performance would be nowhere near the one obtained by properly using a StringBuilder.

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate Jarrod! As to the actual question I guess no one has bothered to attempt to write something to convert string concatenation in a loop into the equivalent string builder setup - I can't think of anything that would prevent it but I assume there's something I'm missing that would mean you can't automate it if this isn't the case.

Comment: I think it's simply punishment for writing dumb code.

Comment: I would agree if not for the fact that in a language where strings were inherently mutable it wouldn't be dumb. Really the expression of an idea is what matters to me and you want to have some smart interpretation of the representation of ideas. String concatenation is pretty damn common and completely incompatable with the notion of immutability (because you're always getting something new with the associated performance costs) so we have this compromise that is obviously confusing. It'd probably all be ok if += operators were extended to StringBuilders to do an append - would look the same.

Comment: Keep in mind that, once the decision had been made and shipped and in the field for more than a few months, it was not possible to change it without the danger of affecting existing code.  Yes, in theory there is no detectable difference between the two major implementation options, but I'd bet that there is some sensitivity somewhere.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure, I could certainly see that between minor releases, but this has been in place since at least Java 6, probably beforehand! You'd have to be doing something very implementation dependant for such an alteration to have an effect anyway, so if this was the case you'd have to test like a hawk on each new (even minor) release pretty thoroughly.

Comment: @berry120 - To my knowledge it's been in place since Java 1.2 or so.  Even if the chance of a sensitivity is slight, there are so many potential exposures that it would be risky to change it.  (There is also some sort of ego thing going on with the Java architects, but I've never been able to parse it.  There are at least two different warring camps.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis exactly; string concatenation is semantic sugar backed by a StringBuilder. The only optimization is that it isn't a StringBuffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So the question has to be - why?

It is not clear why they don't optimize this a bit better in the bytecode compiler.  You would need to ask the Oracle Java compiler team.

One possible explanation is that there may be code in the HotSpot JIT compiler to optimize the bytecode sequence into something better.  (If you were curious, you could modify the code so that it got JIT compiled ... and then capture and examine the native code.  However, you might actually find that the JIT compiler optimizes away the method body entirely ...)

Another possible explanation is that the original Java code is so pessimal to start with that they figured that optimizing it would not have a significant effect.  Consider that a seasoned Java programmer would write it as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++) {
        sb.append("really ");
    }
    sb.append("long string.");
    String s = sb.toString();
}
```

That is going to run roughly **4 orders of magnitude** faster.

---

**UPDATE** - I used the code link from the linked Q&A to find the actual place in Java bytecode compiler source that generates that code:  [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java#Gen.visitAssignop%28com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCAssignOp%29).

There are no hints in the source to explain the "dumb"-ness of the code generation strategy.

---

So to your general Question:

> Does Javac's StringBuilder optimisation do more harm than good?

No.

My understanding is that the compiler developers did extensive benchmarking to determine that (overall) the StringBuilder optimizations are worthwhile.

You have found an edge case in a badly written program that could be optimized better (it is hypothesized).  This is not sufficient to conclude the optimization *"does more harm than good"* overall.

Comment: Hmm kind of agree, but what you say here does kind of contradict with the "write dumb code" unwritten rule of Java development. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html . Why wouldn't the compiler be able to optimize this and cater to the less-than-seasoned Java developers too?

Comment: @Gimby - 1) Yes it does.  It is a well-known exception to that rule.  2) Ask the Java compiler team.  All I can give you is *possible* explanations.

Comment: @Gimby - because it's not possible for the compiler writers to handle "dumb code" for all possibly variations on "dumb".

Comment: @jtahlborn - and because they have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: at all: fair enough I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

> FWIW, my benchmarks (unsurprisingly) put the manual concat() approach 2x3 times faster than using += in a loop with 10,000 elements.

I'm interested to see your benchmark, because mine (based on the excellent [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) harness) shows that `+=` is slightly faster than `String.concat`.  When we perform three operations per loop iteration (`s += "re"; s += "al"; s += "ly ";`), `+=` remains nearly as performant, while `String.concat` takes the obvious factor-of-3 hit.

I ran my benchmark on a [Intel Xeon E5-2695 v2 @ 2.40GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/75281/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2695-v2-30M-Cache-2_40-GHz) running OpenJDK build 1.8.0_40-ea-b23.  There are four implementations:

- implicit, which uses `+=`
- explicit, which explicitly instantiates a StringBuilder for each concatenation, representing the `+=` desugaring
- concat, which uses `String.concat`
- smart, which uses one StringBuilder as in [Stephen C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24615055/3614835)

There are two versions of each implementation: the normal one and one performing three operations in the loop body.

Here are the numbers.  This is throughput, so higher is better.  Error is the bounds of a 99.9% confidence interval.  (This is JMH's default output.)

```
Benchmark                      Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
StringBuilderBench.smart      thrpt   30  5438.676 ± 352.088  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.implicit   thrpt   30    10.290 ±   0.878  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.concat     thrpt   30     9.685 ±   0.924  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.explicit   thrpt   30     9.078 ±   0.884  ops/s

StringBuilderBench.smart3     thrpt   30  3335.001 ± 115.600  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.implicit3  thrpt   30     9.303 ±   0.838  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.explicit3  thrpt   30     8.597 ±   0.237  ops/s
StringBuilderBench.concat3    thrpt   30     3.182 ±   0.228  ops/s
```

The smart implementation using just one StringBuilder is much faster than the others, as expected.  Of the remaining implementations, `+=` beats `String.concat`, which beats explicit StringBuilder instantiation.  They're all fairly close, considering the error.

When performing three operations per loop, all the implementations take a small (relative) hit, except for `String.concat`, whose throughput is reduced by a factor of 3.

These results are not surprising considering HotSpot has specific optimizations for StringBuilder (and StringBuffer) -- see [`src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/c3b117fa5bde/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp).  The [commit history for this file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/log/c3b117fa5bde/src/share/vm/opto/stringopts.cpp) shows these optimizations date to late 2009 as part of bug [JDK-6892658](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6892658).

There don't seem to be any changes between 8u5 and the early access build of 8u40 I ran the benchmark with, so that doesn't explain why we got different results.  (Of course, changes elsewhere in the compiler could have changed the results too.)

---

Here's the benchmark code, which I ran with `java -jar benchmarks.jar -w 5s -wi 10 -r 5s -i 30 -f 1`.  The code and complete log of the benchmark run are [also available as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/jbosboom/61c35a22136675847193).

```
package com.jeffreybosboom.stringbuilderbench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;

@State(Scope.Thread)
public class StringBuilderBench {
    //promote to non-final fields to inhibit constant folding (see JMHSample_10_ConstantFold.java)
    private String really = "really ", long_string = "long string.", re = "re", al = "al", ly = "ly ";
    @Benchmark
    public String implicit() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            s += really;
        s += long_string;
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String explicit() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(really).toString();
        s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(long_string).toString();
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String concat() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            s = s.concat(really);
        s = s.concat(long_string);
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String implicit3() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            s += re;
            s += al;
            s += ly;
        }
        s += long_string;
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String explicit3() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(re).toString();
            s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(al).toString();
            s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(ly).toString();
        }
        s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(long_string).toString();
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String concat3() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            s = s.concat(re);
            s = s.concat(al);
            s = s.concat(ly);
        }
        s = s.concat(long_string);
        return s;
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String smart() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            sb.append(really);
        sb.append(long_string);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    @Benchmark
    public String smart3() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            sb.append(re);
            sb.append(al);
            sb.append(ly);
        }
        sb.append(long_string);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```